# How am I missing this critical point?

Tags: calculus

Given this equation,

$$f(x,y) = x^3 + 3xy^2 - 15x + y^3 - 15y$$

I've calculated these partial derivatives

$$fx = 3x^2 + 3y^2 - 15$$

$$fy = 6xy + 3y^2 - 15$$

Then to obtain the critical values, I use substitution of $x=2y$ to obtain:
$$y = \pm1,  x = \pm2$$

but by taking a 2nd glance at the original equation, I realize I've totally missed $(0,\sqrt{5})$ as a solution.  What is the general approach to avoiding this error?

Comment: To get $x=2y$, you took $3x^2=6xy$ and cancelled the $x$.  When you cancel, consider whether the x factor is zero.

Comment: from where comes $$x=2y$$?

Comment: I got $x = 2y$ from setting $fx = fy = 0$ and then cancelling.  Do I need to consider the y factor might be zero too?

Comment: No, it was only division by $x$ when you went from $x^2=2xy$ to $x=2y$.  You didn't divide by $y$ so you don't need to consider $y=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: we have $$f_x=3x^2+6x-15$$ or you have made a typo
solving $$3x^2+3y^2-15=6xy+3y^2-15$$ we get
$$3x^2-6xy=0$$ and this can factorized into $$3x(x-2y)=0$$

Comment: I did make a typo, my mistake

Comment: I totally see it now thank you @Michael and Dr. Graubner

Answer (score 2):

You obtained $x=2y$ from $3x^2 = 6xy$. But $3x^2 = 6xy$ is also true if $x=0$. So you have to solve for $x=2y$ as you did, but also for $x=0$ which will lead you to $y = \pm \sqrt 5$.